# Relation between two single-table inheritance models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, single-table-inheritance, belongs-to

I have the following two models

```
class ContactField < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Address < ContactField
end

class Phone < ContactField
end
```

and

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Company < Contact
end

class Person < Contact
end
```

I want one contact, no matter is it Company or Person, to have many ContactFields(Addresses and Phones)... So where should I put those **has many** and **belongs to**?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already said it in plain english :-)

> I want one contact, no matter is it Company or Person, to have many ContactFields(Addresses and Phones)... So where should I put those has many and belongs to? Thanks

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :contact_fields
end

class ContactField < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :contact
end
```

This Relationship will be inherited by both address and phone

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're describing a belongs to relationship. The associations should be defined in the parent class, so they can be inherited by the subclasses.

```
class ContactField < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :company, :foreign_key => :contact_id
  belongs_to :person, :foreign_key => :contact_id
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contact_fields
  has_many :addresses
  has_many :phones
end
```

However @contact.contact_fields will just return ContactField records. If you need the methods defined in any of the sub classes you can always use the becomes method. There are a few ways around that. Such adding the extra associations, like I did. Or using [ActiveRecord::Base#becomes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002334)